# Specflow feature file statistics generation?

Tags: bdd, specflow

We have several feature files across multiple folders, with different tags on each scenario (Eg @reliable, @ignore, @proposed, @smoketest).

We'd like to generate a report automatically on how many scenarios we have, whether they're tagged or not, across each folder.

Is there a plugin available for that, or are we going to have to write a basic script to process them?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SpecRun](http://www.specrun.com/).
Probably, it doesn't help to get a report automatically, but you will able to see a statistic from the test window.

With SpecRun, you can run and debug your scenarios as first class citizens: 
From the test window, you can:

- group the scenarios by tags (choose "Traits" grouping) and features (choose "Class");
- filter scenarios by different criteria

https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/SpecRun-Integration

Comment: Yeah, we have Specrun, although I didn't realise you can group by traits (although in our version it's 'categories'. It almost does what we want, except when a scenario has multiple tests - it counts them all as just one :/  May have to write a custom tool...

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried [Pickles](https://github.com/x97mdr/pickles/wiki)?

*Pickles is an open source living documentation generator that works on feature files written in the Gherkin language, popularized in tools like Cucumber and SpecFlow.*